# Merge Clock With System Tray

Tags: gnome-shell, system-tray, clock

I was wondering if it was possible to merge the clock into the system tray in Ubuntu 18.04 to make look like Chrome OS's system tray:

[image: Like this]

Comment: I have that installed already the lock is still indepentent

Comment: Hi, do you mean I need to compare it with chrome 0S? can you attach a pic of chrome 0S clock for reference?

Comment: It's been added now

Comment: I'm sorta new to linux so I wouldn't know where to start

Comment: Hi.. I am not a programming background guy.. editing hard coded files in this case requires programming knowledge or atleast who prepares gnome-shell extensions can make one for you.. I can sponser bounty for you if someone comes to write it for you..

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/bounty

Comment: yes.. but I wish to do that if some one is really interested to write it for sure..

Comment: Ubuntu has a top panel with the clock. Ubuntu doesn't have a bottom panel like Chrome OS. There ARE GNOME extensions however, that WILL move the top panel to the bottom, or that WILL create an extra bottom panel, and some may also add a second clock, as per your request. See https://extensions.gnome.org